# How to run code before each test case in all tests in MiniTest?

Tags: ruby, minitest

I need to run code before each test in all my tests in MiniTest.

Before I did:

```
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase.add_setup_hook do
   ...code to run before each test
end
```

After I upgraded MiniTest to version 4.7.2 it shows the following error:

```
undefined method `add_setup_hook' for MiniTest::Unit::TestCase:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I am using Ruby MRI 2.0.0p0.

**SOLUTION**

```
module MyMinitestPlugin
  def before_setup
    super
    # ...code to run before all test cases
  end

  def after_teardown
    # ... code to run after all test cases
    super
  end
end

class MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  include MyMinitestPlugin
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`add_setup_hook` was removed in 4.6.0.
https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/commit/792a480ebeb32983b9150adae575b7c396e2ae63

Use [`before_setup`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Unit/LifecycleHooks.html#method-i-before_setup) instead.

Comment: Warning: From documentation: "This hook is meant for libraries to extend minitest. It is not meant to be used by test developers."

Answer (score 2):

I think that you're looking for the [`setup()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/minitest/unit/rdoc/MiniTest/Unit/TestCase.html#method-i-setup) method.

Comment: There's also the [`teardown()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/minitest/unit/rdoc/MiniTest/Unit/TestCase.html#method-i-teardown) method which is partner for `setup`.

Comment: I am not sure it is what I am looking for. I need a way to run code before each test case in ALL my test suites. For example, I have 10 test files. I want to setup it once so it runs before each test case in all 10 files.

Answer (score 1):

If using MiniTest, you can set that in `test/test_helper.rb`:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
...
    setup do
         ...code to run before each test
    end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

**Update 2019**

Don't write a plugin for this, plugins are intended for gems which extend Minitest functionality, not for test authors.

If you write Minitest Specs, you can do the following instead:

```
class Minitest::Spec
  before :each do
    [do stuff]
  end
end
```